# Recently Switched from ATOM to VS Code, need aid with the multi-selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently switched from Atom to VS Code and i'm struggling with the multi-selection, on Atom I could select an A1 point and with shift+click an A2 point to select everything from A1 to A2 then add a new cursor by Ctrl+click on a B1 point and again shift+click to select a B2 point, so I had two separate lines selected... On VS Code, if I select a point A1, A2 and B1, when I shift+click on B2 it selects everything between A1 and B2 :/

How i can achieve the effect of this gif? (made on Atom)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

you have to it different for the first cursor

- click on A1
- Shift+Click A2
- Alt+Click drag from B1 to B2
- Alt+Click drag from C1 to C2

**Edit**

Alternative

- Mouse-Down on A1
- Alt-Down
- Drag to A2
- Mouse-Up
- Mouse-Down on B1, Drag to B2, Mouse-Up
- Mouse-Down on C1, Drag to C2, Mouse-Up
- Alt-Up

Comment: Yes thank you, i was aware of these techniques but, i meant if it's possible to do exactly what i asked with an extension or something? I mean without drag/slide the cursor?

Comment: @NitramO AFAIK you can't customize mouse actions

Comment: So it's impossible to achieve this effect in VS Code? Is there a place where i can ask/suggest for this behavior for futures updates?

Comment: @NitramO you can try the VSC repo issue page